# Unix - How can I send a message to multiple processes?

Tags: sockets, unix, udp, ipc, openwrt

I have a process A that needs to send a message to all process of type B that are running. The process A doesn't know about these other processes, they can be created and destroyed depending on external factors, thus I can have a varying number of process of type B running.

I thought I could use an UDP socket in the process A to send messages to a port P and have all my processes of type B to listen to this port P and receive the a copy of the message.

Is that possible?

I am working with Linux OpenWRT.

I am trying with LuaSockets, but I am getting a "address already in use" error. It seems that I can not have multiples applications to listen to the same port ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

It could be useful to use shared memory if all the processes are local to a single machine.

Have a look at http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/shm_overview.7.html for an explanation.

In short you will need the master process to create a shared memory region and write the data into it. The slave processes can then check the data in the memory region and if it has been changed act upon it. This is however just one of many ways to accomplish this problem. You could also look into using pipes and tee.

Comment: Thanks, I am checking this solution. I checked pipes but I just found communication between two process. I don't know about tee, I'll check it too

Comment: As I am using OpenWRT (I just edited mu question to specify this) it uses uClib and it does not support shm functions =/. If I use tee I need to specify the destinations, but my process A does not know the destinations.

Comment: @Lilás This could benefit from using a set of named pipes, a good trick is to have one pipe which when a new process B is created it writes it's PID into the pipe which process A is reading. When this happens process A must make a new named pipe named after the PID of the process B, A must then tee to the new named pipe, and process B must read it (B already knows of the pipe's name as it is B's PID). Finally when a process B closes process A must listen or a SIGHUP to show B has closed the named pipe and delete it. Hope that helps. :)